# Check the language of string based on glyphs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, arabic

I have a MySQL database with book titles in both English and Arabic and I'm using a [PHP class](http://www.ar-php.com/php/arabic/index.html) that can automatically transliterate Arabic text into Latin script.

I'd like my output HTML to look something like this:

```
<h3>A book</h3>
<h3>كتاب <em>(kitaab)</em></h3>
<h3>Another book</h3>
```

Is there a way for PHP to determine the language of a string based on the Unicode characters and glyphs used in it? I'm trying to get something like this:

```
$Ar = new Arabic('EnTransliteration');
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    ...
    if (some test to see if $item['item_title'] has Arabic glyphs in it) {
      echo "<h3>$item[item_title] <em>(" . $Ar->ar2en($item['item_title']) . ")</em></h3>";
    } else {
      echo "<h3>$item[item_title]</h3>";
    }
    ...
}
```

Fortunately the class doesn't choke when fed Latin characters, so in theory I could send every result through the transformation, but that seems like a waste of processing.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I still haven't found a way to check for glyphs or characters. I suppose I could put all the Arabic characters in an array and check if anything in the array matches a part of the string...

I did, however, figure out an interim solution that might work fine in the end. It puts every title through the transformation regardless of language, but only outputs the parenthetical transliteration if the string was changed:

```
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_results)) {
    $transliterate = trim(strtolower($Ar->ar2en($item['item_title'])));
    $item_title = (strtolower($item['item_title']) == $transliterate) ? $item['item_title'] : $item['item_title'] . " <em>($transliterate)</em>";

    echo "<h3>$item_title</h3>";
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you already know this but.. you do realize transliteration is the worst way to translate things, proper multilangual systems (I've worked with many) use professionals to manually translate things and store each language's version of text.  The differences are painfully obvious, take Spanish to English, with transliteration the Spanish-> English would read "The house red big" instead of "The big red house".

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm not translating. I'm just making it so non-Arabic readers can get the gist of what is in our catalog of books, since the Arabic books we have are and will be cataloged in Arabic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $item['item_title'])
```

You could make that regular expression a bit more sophisticated if you want to, but I don't think you really need to.

The [`\p` escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.unicode) lets you select characters based on their Unicode properties (when the [`u` pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is used).

The PHP manual mentions: "Extended properties such as "Greek" or "InMusicalSymbols" are not supported by PCRE." But that's not entirely true anymore. [PCRE release 6.5 added support for script names](http://www.pcre.org/news.txt).

Comment: Wow! What is the \p modifier? I've never seen that! It works perfectly though! I've noticed that in some server configurations it won't work right because of the PCRE configuration. Is this true?

Comment: I've clarified my answer. I presume some servers have an older PCRE version?

Comment: Yeah, I think that was the main issue I found in my Google research--some PHP configurations use Apache's PCRE rather than PHP's newer, fancier one, so preg_match()es with /p (or a whole host of other modifiers) will fail. I think it's pretty rare, though; all my servers use 7.0 (most 7.8 even).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an PHP open source class for Arabic character set auto detection:

http://www.ar-php.com/php/arabic/index.html#ArCharsetD

Comment: The database fields are all set with `utf8_unicode_ci` collation. Does that mean that they are all utf-8 encoded?

Comment: That's actually the same class I'm using for the transliteration. Sadly, though, the ArCharsetD chokes on any English strings I feed it...