# How can i Match arabic letters using regexp in php

Tags: php, regex, arabic

How can i Match arabic letters with regexp in php

My Code

```
$name = $_GET("name");

if (arabic letters only and spaces) // using regexp
```

Comment: You might find http://alex-csed.blogspot.com/2010/03/tutorial-validating-users-arabic-input.html to be relevant.

Answer (score 10):

I think your answer is here:
[Check the language of string based on glyphs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011841/check-the-language-of-string-based-on-glyphs-in-php)

```
if(preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $name])) {
echo 'valid';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. how can I add arabic to ^[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s(?!\s)){4,14}[^\s]$

Answer (score -1):

I am using PHP version 7.3.33 and the following solution worked for me.

```
if(preg_match("/^[\x{0621}-\x{064A} ]+$/u", $name])) {
 echo 'Yes, it contains Arabic letters only and spaces';
}
```

Comment: PHP 7.3.33 is outdated since **years**. Please update ASAP