# Match Arabic/English Alphanumeric using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that matches:

- Arabic letters.
- List item
- English alphanumeric.
- 3 Spaces maximum.
- 4 Underscores maximum.

Any order.

---

I tried varies solution but couldn't solve it.

**Here is what i have now:**

```
preg_match('@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}[^\W_]*$@', $username)
```

The above expression allows:

- 3 spaces maximum
- English alpanumerics
- No underscore allowed

Comment: Arabic letter - I correct understand you ? You mean some like this :أ ?ت ث ج ح خ د ذ ر ز س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ك ل م ن ه و ي

Comment: In any order? Is "a_o _e _u" ok and "_a_o_h_t _" not ok and "a o e u i d" not ok? Or should first letters come and then spaces and then underscores?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i Match arabic letters using regexp in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145742/how-can-i-match-arabic-letters-using-regexp-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about arabic characters, but the following regexp should match the others

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})\s{0,3}_{0,4}
```

This will match
(Alphanumeric)(0-3 spaces)(0-4 underscores)

If there are more than 4 underscores, the last ones will be omitted
If there are more than 3 spaces then the part after the 3 spaces will be ignored.

EDIT:
For arabic letters: First declare a string containing all arabic letters
so you'll have

```
$arabic='all_arabic_letters';
```

Then your regexp string will be

```
$regex='[' . $arabic . ']{1,}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})\s{0,3}_{0,4}';
```

And match it as follows:

```
preg_match($regex, $username);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if your Regex flavour supports this `\p{Arabic}` or `\p{InArabic}`.

Also experiment with mb_ereg_match() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php

If that doesn't work, there is no other option than explicitly writing all arabic characters into the expression. Messy, but does the work.

Since you are using php, you can first list all arabic characters into a string variable and then add that variable to regex, for the code manageability's sake.

Comment: And he can look here: [How can i Match arabic letters using regexp in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145742/how-can-i-match-arabic-letters-using-regexp-in-php)

Comment: Yes. If his regex flavour (version) supports unicode. If not, he has to use my 2.nd solution.