# What is a regular expression to filter any special characters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

What is a regular expression to filter any special characters?

I want to remove any characters except 0-9 a-z A-Z and standard universal alphabet (arabic).

For example remove these characters: `` `~!@#$%^&*()_+=-\][{}|';lL:"/.,<>? `` and any others.

Comment: What is "standard universal alphabet (arabic)"? If you know exactly which characters it covers, add them to Sjoerd's answer and you have your solution.

Comment: Bad form to downvote an answer and then suggest someone use that as a base to work off.

Comment: See [this question's top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011841/check-the-language-of-string-based-on-glyphs-in-php/1021799#1021799) for how to match Arabic characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9]~', '', $text);
```

Comment: -1 Does not remove "standard universal alphabet (arabic)" as requested.

Comment: it dosent support arabic language

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "standard universal alphabet (arabic)". Try with the [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: For example i want to use this string:

$a = 'سلام %$!@%&*%&()^..'; 

and filter any char except 'سلام'

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Arabic}\pN]*/u', '', $str);
```