# Search engine for Arabic letters in php

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

I'm trying to create search engine using php for search arabic letters from my database but I didn't get anything, but my code working fine with english letters and numbers.....
here my code

```
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  if(empty($name)) { 
                    echo"Plz enter the Search"; 
                    }

  if(preg_match("/^[(a-z) (A-Z) (0-9)]+/u", $name)){ 

//connect  to the database 
  $db=mysql_connect ("localhost",  "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect  to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 
//select  the database to use 
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("student"); 
  mysql_set_charset("utf8");
   $sql="SELECT id, fname, lname FROM st_information WHERE id LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR fname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR lname LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'"; 
//Run  the query against the mysql query function 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
//Create  while loop and loop through result set 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            $FirstName  =$row['fname']; 
            $LastName=$row['lname']; 
            $ID=$row['id']; 
//Display the result of the array 
    echo "<ul>\n"; 
    echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"show.php?id=$ID\">"   .$FirstName .  " " .$LastName .  "</a></li>\n"; 
    echo "</ul>"; 
  } 
  }

 }     
  }
```

Comment: Is your form input UTF8?

Comment: this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: yes I'm using <meta> tag with charset=utf8

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Guess that `/^[(a-z) (A-Z) (0-9)]+/u` won't match any arabic chars.

Comment: BTW: you can set the enconding in a meta tag, in the http header and in the form with the accept-charset attribute. HTML meta tags and HTTP header encoding settings are not 100% reliable, browsers can be set to encode pages differently which will cause the form input to be sent in this browser setting encoding, to force a certain charset in every case use the accept-charset attribute.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Try to break the problem down a bit and explain in more details what does and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^[(a-z) (A-Z) (0-9)]+/u` won't match any arabic chars of course.

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011841/check-the-language-of-string-based-on-glyphs-in-php):

```
preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $string)
```

Of course, beware of SQL injection and move to `PDO` or `mysqli` as already pointed out.