# Multiple language php application

Tags: php, translation

Currently I have my php application running on english. We have to now cater for few other languages. We notice some do a whole set of translation of the all the form and put in a new folder label according to the translated language. Is that an optimize method?

Comment: No, it's not an optimize method.

Comment: @AndyGee what do you suggest then ?

Comment: Well how do you store your data which will be translated? A database? html files? Do you use a template system?

Comment: Placeholders and database. Echo each placeholder through a method, which takes from the DB this placeholder and returns the translation according to which lang the user has set

Comment: In that case you should run the translation on the database tables. Add an extra column for each new language and request the data depending on the language.

Comment: @AndyGee yes for those which I require to list from db I plan to do your suggestion of additional column. How about the php form, data grid labeling etc? Should I use separate form for different languages?

Comment: @user2711681 No, you can use separate CSS depending on the language. For example for Arabic languages, you can use some RTL things, to make the grid Right to Left, etc.

Comment: It depends on the number of translations. You could use one php include file for all languages. `$lang['fr']['submit'] = 'soumettre';`

Comment: My languages are going to be more on polish,russian, spanish, portugese etc. I plan to create separate folders with respective language php files in it.

Comment: I still wonder why not database, but files?

Comment: How to use database I am not clear? Offcourse for thins like my combo list I will use the database. How about forms as I got form to create a new user which require to enter user name, password, address, id number. Then we also got a range of javascript error message how to handle those via database?

Comment: I couldn't make it as comment, it was too long. I've posted and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still for the idea of database.

Let's say you have input field, next to it there is "Username" in english, it's value by default is "Enter your username". You can have something like:

```
<td><?=$obj->translate('username');?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$obj->translate('enter_username');?>" /></td>
```

So you have i.e. in your db table `translations`:

```
id | placeholder     |         en          |    pl                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | username        |      Username       | Nazwa użytkownika          |
2  | enter_username  | Enter your username | Wprowadź nazwę użytkownika |
```

So your client is polish, you set him `$_SESSION['language'] = 'pl'`

You build function/method translate(), which returns the current language translation.

```
public function translate($word) {
    $sql = "SELECT $_SESSION['language'] FROM translations WHERE placeholder = '$word';";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->result();
}
```

So basicly, when you run `$obj->translate('enter_username');` for your Polish client, you make query like this:

```
SELECT pl FROM translations WHERE placeholder = 'enter_username';
```

which returns 'Wprowadź nazwę użytkownika'

Everytime you need something to be printed, you have to insert it's placeholder in your db, and later or immediately it's translations.

If you need and error alert via javascript, for wrong username for example, you add a placeholder in the db i.e. 'wrong_username_from_login_form" lately translated in English as "You have entered wrong username. Please go back and try again".

You can have:

```
<script>
alert("<?=$obj->translate('wrong_username_from_login_form');?>");
</script>
```

If your client is English, he will have alerted on its screen: "You have entered wrong username. Please go back and try again"

Comment: @But this gonna cause me a lot of db operation right cause each word I need to do a search look up. how about the javascript part ?

Comment: The query is simple. You have one column search for one placeholder in WHERE. Even million queries about this will not slow down the core. About the JS - look the edit of the answer

Comment: Most of my javascript error message are e.g. feeError.innerHTML = " * Fee must only contain digits";  I am also using these filters var isNumeric = /^[0-9]+$/; var isLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; how will these be effected ?

Comment: placeholder=`"fee_only_digits_allowed"`, english=`" * Fee must only contain digits "`. `feeError.innerHTML = "<?=$obj->translate('fee_only_digits_allowed');?>";` So your feeError variable will be "* Fee must only contain digits" at compile time of your script for ENGLISH users, and whatever it is in polish, etc.. :) Everywhere you have a text, you need to use the method and the placeholder passed as parameter. isNumeric and isLetters are regex's which you don't need to translate. Only feeRror needs translation here. As I said - everywhere you echo something.

Comment: how will my isLetter be effect with the different letter from different languages ?

Comment: In the mentioned languages, it will have no problem, since the layouts are the same. With a veeery little exceptions. You might have problems with languages as Arabic or similar. Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011841/check-the-language-of-string-based-on-glyphs-in-php . You might need to change the regex

Comment: Ok let me explore. How about using include file like suggested by Andy Gee what is your opinion on this?

Comment: You will end up with the same problem. If user is Russian, whatever file you include, if he types "Ты" in your box, the isLetter regex will not catch it as letter. You would need a change again. However, using files seems for me too static solution, also doesn't allow you easily to create a tool for translation. You can make a simple form which interacts with `translations` table and insert placeholders, on the other hand, to list them and allow your co-workers to translate from english to i.e. polish via your tool, without editing files or altering the db from themself

Comment: Let's say you need to change placeholder somewhere. If you change "submit" to "submit_button", you would need to open every file and change $lang[..]['Submit'] to $lang[...]['Submit_button']. In my case you will need only to update the `placeholder` column.

Comment: So how to solve those regex problem with russian language per your e.g "Ты"

Comment: It is another question, you have to put in in `javascript` tag. How to match if users types letter in any of the known languages. I bet you can achieve it by [a-Z][а-Я], or how the answerer in the given link said with /p modifier and "Russian", but I guess this works only in PHP, not in JS. So, make a question about this in javascript. P.S.: I think you can match if user didn't type Digit or Special char, so if not - you assume it's letter.

Comment: Ok I will create another question tagged as javascript on how to handle this issue of isLetter. How about digit do these language have different digits for their own languages?

Comment: I don't think so. There two types of digits (numbers, in this case) known. Arabic, which are most popular and worldwide used `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, and Rome (which I don't think are digits, they are just letters and are used for lists) -> `I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X` you know, when you write a document, you have first paragraph `I. Something` then `1. Something else`. Rome numbers commonly use letters "I, V, X, L", but you don't need to match them. Mentioned languages in your question use 1-9 - all of them :)

Comment: I am just worried is the now where should I put the query you suggest should it be in an include file?

Comment: Depends on how you app is built. My suggestion is particulary if you have something like classloader and the helper class, there the method is used is instantiated in every of your files as `$obj = new Helper().` So Helper() contains `translate($word)` and you use `$obj->translate('...');` If you don't use some architecture as MVC and classloading, you can have a separate file which contains this function (not as class-method, but as function), so you need to include the file in each of your files, but then you can access the function without object :)

Comment: @No I dont have classloader and helper class. I do some include file mainly to keep the db connection. So I guess I will run a function then which calls the db operation right?

Comment: So after the connection, you can have this function :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use files that contains your sentences(or use database) and include them according to selected language.

For example :

**Language_FR.txt:**

```
hello = 'Salut'
delete='Supprimer'
```

**Language_EN.txt:**

```
hello = 'Hello !'
delete='Delete'
```

Comment: yes I plan to create separate files for each language accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of translations. You could use one php include file for all languages or break each language into a separate file.

```
$lang['en']['submit'] = 'submit';//english
$lang['fr']['submit'] = 'soumettre';//french
$lang['es']['submit'] = 'presentar';//spanish
```

and in your placeholder based html with

```
<?php
$lang = 'fr'; //set the language somewhere
<button><?=$tang[$lang]['submit'];?></button>
?>
```

This would output `<button>soumettre</button>`

Don't make a copy of the entire site though or editing will mean editing translation count number of times each time you want to make a change.

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations basically use a look-up table indexed by the language
(either in a database or a text file).

Then in your code whenever you display a user interface element you would have a function that looks up the correct string for the language you want to display.

A very simple way might be with including the right file depending on the language.

In your text file (lets call it 'de.php') something like:

> $lang[] = ['Are you Sure?']['Sind Sie sicher?'];
>
> $lang[] = ['Cancel']['Abbrechen'];

then your code could have:

> //load the appropriate language
>
> include($userLang.".php");
>
> ....
>
> echo $lang['Are you sure?'];

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to store translations for user interface elements (let's call them 'static') in your database. Instead use a localization file format that is appropriate for your technology. When using PHP, this could be Gettext (PO), CSV or just a simple PHP Array file.

Advantages:
- You can send your files to a translator/translation service without having to extract them from the database
- You don't have to ship database dumps for a development/staging version of your application
- You can use your translations very easy for another technology
- Speed: Parsing a CSV/Ini file in PHP is way faster than performing n queries on every page

I think Andy Gee and FaceOfJock displayed quite nicely how your solution should look like.