# Confusion regarding preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I'm trying to check if $oneAya is inside the string "هُوَ الْمَلِكُ الْقُدُّوسُ" but whenever I try the code below, it prints "not found".. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$oneAya = "هُوَ";
if(preg_match($oneAya,"هُوَ الْمَلِكُ الْقُدُّوسُ")) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: you can't literally use the characters you are using but rather things like their unicode reference. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011841/check-the-language-of-string-based-on-glyphs-in-php) out for some interesting answers

Comment: @Matt I skimmed through the post, thing is.. I just want to compare 2 arabic texts and check if one is exactly available in the other, while in that post, OP wants to check if the text has arabic text. Any other suggestions on how I could tackle such a problem?

Comment: [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/mb-strpos) is your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your regex is not prepared thoroughly: you didn't put delimiters.

```
$oneAya = "/هُوَ/";
if(preg_match($oneAya,"هُوَ الْمَلِكُ الْقُدُّوسُ")) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Secondly, if your PCRE is compiled with UTF-8 then you are fine, however `preg_match()` does much on solving your problem, simply you are in need of [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/mb_strpos):

```
if (mb_strpos("هُوَ الْمَلِكُ الْقُدُّوسُ", "هُوَ") !== false) {
    echo 'Found.';
}
```

Comment: What if the word I'm trying to find is a substring of another word, wouldn't that print "Found"? (example: mb_strpos("He", "Hello World") would that print found?)

Comment: You should use it this way: `mb_strpos("Hello World", "He")` (substring as second argument) and yes it will find it. @OmarHashim

Answer (score 1):

You need to delimit the regular expression, and use the Unicode modifier:

```
$oneAya = '/هُوَ/u';
```

Without the delimiters the regular expression engine does not know how to parse it. The Unicode modifier is needed if you want to match anything outside the ASCII character range.